# How to translate "Cart Subtotal:" and "Order Total:" Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation

I cant find Cart Subtotal in the woocommerce pot file. I am busy translating it to Afrikaans language.

"Cart Subtotal" is on the emails and on "Order Received" page.

I tried to find it in the code by using dreamweaver to search in the entire folder. Can not find it.

Did someone also have this problem? Any advice for me? ps this my first question here :) (i did search for this first on stackoverflow)

Comment: The string "cart subtotal" doesn't seem to exist in WooCommerce. The default label should be "Subtotal:" Are you sure it isn't coming from your theme?

Comment: Hi, that is true, i also have vendors plugin installed so i will search in there also. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can go to plugins/woocommerce/templates.

There you can find the files.

Copy those files to theme-folder/woocommerce and do the required changes.